# Singleton (Traditional vs Enum)

Tags: java, singleton, enum-class

Disclaimer: Apologies if this question is too basic.

I'm learning about Singleton and have a quick question its implementation, are these differences purely coding preferences or am I missing something?

**Singleton Class**

```
public enum SerialNumberGen {
INSTANCE;

private int count;

public synchronized int getNextSerial(){
    return count++;
}
```

**Example Implementation**

```
.println(SerialNumberGenerator.INSTANCE.getNextSerial());
```

**My implementation**

```
SerialNumberGen gen = SerialNumberGen.INSTANCE;
System.out.println(gen.getNextSerial());
```

Is my implementation still adhering to the Singleton pattern? Or is this how Enum classes are supposed to be referenced.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: [Read this](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ImmutableEnumChecker) before considering a mutable enum.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Now, after you have learned about the *Singelton* (Pattern): **forget it!** A Singelton is merily a *global variable* of which we know from 60 years of programming history to be bad idea.

Comment: `SerialNumberGen gen = SerialNumberGen.INSTANCE;` Why did you redundantly set a variable to hold the one and only enum constant of the type, instead of just using the constant directly?

Comment: @LewBloch How would you reference it? I did this so I'd only have to type out the shorter:  "gen.getWhateverMethod" instead of "SerialNumberGenerator.INSTANCE.getWhateverMethod()"

Comment: Worried you might sprain a finger typing all that?

Comment: @LewBloch That's a weird way to reference it, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my implementation still adhering to the Singleton pattern?

Yes. You still have exactly one instance of `SerialNumberGen`.

There's no difference between the two, aside from the additional variable in the second case.

---

You should think carefully about having a mutable `enum`. [The view epoused by Google's Java libraries team](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ImmutableEnumChecker) is:

> Static state is dangerous to begin with, but much worse for enums. We all think of enum values as constants – and even refer to them as “enum constants” – and would be very surprised if any of their state ever changed, or was not thread-safe.

Whilst enums are a convenient way to create thread-safe creation of singletons, they aren't necessarily well-suited to what you're doing here.

For me, the bigger question here is *why do you think you need a singleton?* I suggest you read and thoroughly consider [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

There's nothing here that *really* requires a singleton. You can simply have a single instance of `SerialNumberGen`, which you have injected everywhere that needs it.

Comment: So it is just a matter of coding preference? I simply didn't want to type out the long line of code so I made an object of the class and referenced it, but that's still cool?

Comment: If you don't want such a "long" line of code, consider 1) using a static import; 2) buying a bigger monitor.

Comment: I'm only learning Design principles/patterns for Java, so there's no real necessity for a singleton, other than learning how it works - I just wanted to check if the example we're given is the best or only way to implement it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "other than learning how it works" A really important thing to learn is why you *shouldn't* use it, really. Singletons are a pain in the derriere. Learn about dependency injection instead.

Comment: "pain in the derriere"... Made my day. Upvote just for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a singleton.

But please note: the much better approach is to encapsulate the specific behavior into an interface, so that

```
public enum ServiceProvider implements Service {
```

so that you can do

```
Service service = ServiceProvider.INSTANCE
```

for example. And going from there; I even create an **ordinary**

```
class ServiceImpl implements Service {
```

and then do

```
public enum ServiceProvider implements Service {
  INSTANCE;

   private final Service delegate = new ServiceImpl()
```

as that helps to further separate the responsibilities of

1. providing that service interface
2. providing a singleton

And it also helps with when writing unit tests.

Comment: Thank you, I think we'll be moving onto this kind of implementation down the line, just on the basics for now, but I'll certainly keep it in mind!

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad you find my input helpful.